# Создание отчета

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Пишу программу учета, там менеджер заносит в форму все нужные данные, после чего это все должно распечататься в определенном виде.

То есть есть листок, там текст и поля, куда обычно люди вносили все ручкой. Моя задача чтобы этот документ подгружался в программу и в эти поля заносились данные из формы, которую заполнит менеджер. Так вот, подскажите, что лучше использовать:

- В WPF есть потоковые документы. Я думал, может сформировать документ в XAML, потом его загружать и подставлять в нужные места данные, а потом на печать.
- Или есть статья о том, как создать документ вордовский с помощью шарпа сформировать, а потом распечатывать.

Что лучше использовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не знаю, как в `WPF`, но я подобную задачу решал на `web`. Для ее решения я использовал `stimulsoft report` (у них есть решение и для `wpf`). Схема работы следующая: создаете форму для ввода данных, в `report` системе задаете шаблон для документа (во встроенном редакторе), данные передаются в шаблон и на их основе строится документ. А пользователь уже сам решает, в каком виде ему нужно импортировать документ, `xls`, `doc`, `pdf` или что-то еще. Преимуществом такого решения является тот момент, что подобный подход позволяет производить сложные манипуляции с данными, а потом передавать их для генерации отчета.